# Does 'pay some effort' make a question about negligible performance valid?

Tags: discussion, questions

I just see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34014906) question about performance of a line of code, it is quite well-receiving now, but unfortunately this type of questions may receive negative feedback like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32387181).

To be my honest, I may learn a lot new skills from these type of questions even the original performance problem is not useful :) Also, the performance may be negligible for you but not for some framework developers (I guess!)

But in my impression, this type of questions are often closed unless OP give some effort to find the answers. My question is: is asking negligible performance problem OK only if OP show some efforts to find the answer?

Comment: Many of these types of questions *aren't* asked appropriately.  That doesn't mean that they *can't* be, it just means that most people don't bother to ask them well.  Your two examples already demonstrate that.

Comment: Something's performance is objective because it can be measured. Questions asking for solutions that are "better" or "the best" cannot be objectively measured, that makes them subjective. Stack Overflow is not a place for subjective answers.

Comment: I don't agree that those are the same type of question though. The former is researched with test results which makes it a far more successful question, the second is just outsourcing the effort.